# JavaScript - outputting multiple arrays of submitted user input on screen

Tags: javascript, forms, function, input, markup

I'm trying to take the user input of the form and on submit, populate a space in the DOM with the input. I also want to be able to print multiple user inputs in the same space (i.e. something like printing an array of user inputs onto the page each time a user submits)

```
function create_list_markup() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
        "<h1 class='list-title'>"
        + document.getElementById('title').value + "</h1>"
        + "<br><br>"
        + "Recipient: "
        + document.getElementById('recipient').value
        + "<br>" + "Link: "
        + document.getElementById('link').value
        + "<br>"
        + "Price: "
        + document.getElementById('price').value;
}

function create_gift_markup(gift) {
    const markup = `
        <p>
            <span class=''> ${gift.title} </span><br>
            <span class=''> ${gift.recipient} </span><br>
            <span class=''> ${gift.link} </span><br>
            <span class=''> ${gift.price} </span><br>
        </p>`;
    return markup;
}

function insert_gifts(gift_markup) {
    const gift_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    gift_markup.forEach(function __append_markup_to_docfrag(markup) {
        let container_element = document.createElement('span');
        container_element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
        gift_fragment.appendChild(container_element.firstElementChild);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(gift_fragment);
}

function create_list_markup() {
    const gift_markup = create_gift_markup(gifts)
    insert_gifts(gift_markup)
}
```

The create_list_markup function works and prints out the user input to the screen (in conjunction with a div with an id of "display"), however I wanted to print multiple outputs to the same space, so I wrote the rest of the code. That's the stuff that doesn't work.

Here is the markup:

```
  <h1>Christmas Gifts</h1>

  <form class="gift-form" name="giftform" action="" id="gift">
      <h2>Gift Submit Form</h2>
      <label>Title of Gift</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Enter a title" id="title">
      <label>Recipient of Gift</label>
      <input type="text" name="recipient" value="" placeholder="Enter a recipient" id="recipient">
      <label>Link to Gift Picture</label>
      <input type="text" name="link" value="" placeholder="Enter link to picture" id="link">
      <label>Price of Gift</label>
      <input type="text" name="price" value="" placeholder="Enter price" id="price">
      <button type="button" value="Submit" onClick="create_list_markup()">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <div class="list-box">
      <h2>Gift List</h2>
      <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can clean up your code a bit by using the multi-line string in your `create_list_markup()` function also, will make this easier to read.

Comment: Can you add the HTML source here too?

Comment: `create_list_markup` function is defined twice.

Comment: @ppovoski I added the HTML source